# What is the best way to adapt Model/FormControl values to be shown differently in the UI control?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Simple example:

I have a flag in my model and would like to show it as a check box control but inverted.

Model:

```
{isSupported: true}
```

Display Control:

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="isSupported">Is NOT supported</input>
```

So in this case I would like to show the inverted bool value in the UI input control.

**Known but unsatisfying solutions:**

1. Adapt value before/at control initialization and before submitting the form. [This adds complexity in places where it does not belong.]
2. Adapt visualization or model to match the other. [Often not desirable.]
3. Write a custom ControlValueAccessor. [This often will not work e.g. if a used library/framework/control like e.g. material is already using a custom ControlValueAccessor.]

My current "solution" is to wrap the UI control and use there a proxy ControlValueAccessor which includes the required transformation. Is there a better solution for this?